# "suggestd quit unexpectedly" means what?

Tags: mac, macos

What does the alert box statement "suggestd quit unexpectedly" mean?  It turned up on my iMac , OS Sierra 10.12.  I have attached a screenshot.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the ~/Library/Suggestions and restarting your Mac.

Using terminal:

```
mv ~/Library/Suggestion ~/.Trash
```

This will move it to the trash incase you want to revert back.

Reboot your Mac and it should begin working.